# Refused to load the script Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a call to this site and receive a json object back. How can I interface with this API properly within my chrome extension given CSP?

> Error: Refused to load the script 'http://thesaurus.altervista.org/service.php?word=smile&language=en_US&output=json&key=REMOVEDMYKEY&callback=thesaurus' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

```
var word = "smile";
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://thesaurus.altervista.org/service.php?word="+ word +"&language=en_US&output=json&key=REMOVEDMYKEY&callback=thesaurus";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
function thesaurus(result) { 
  output = "";
  for (key in result.response) { 
list = result.response[key].list; 
output += list.synonyms+"<br>"; 
} 
if (output) 
document.getElementById("synonyms").innerHTML = output; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you show expressly says that it can return a JSON object. Callback (JSONP-style) is optional.

You *cannot* use JSONP from that domain due to Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) for extensions. While you can [add whitelisted domains](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script) to the policy, HTTP origins are forbidden for security reasons.

Instead, you want to capture a JSON response as a string instead and parse it.

You need to do an [XHR call](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) to that URL:

```
function thesaurus(word) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    try {
      var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // Do something with the result
    } catch(e) {
      // Invalid JSON response
    }
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    // Something bad happened
  }
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "http://thesaurus.altervista.org/service.php?word=" + word +
      "&language=en_US&output=json&key=REMOVEDMYKEY", 
    true
  );
  xhr.send();
}
```

And you may need host permissions in your manifest to do that, unless that server has enabled CORS from any origin (which would make sense for such an API, by the way).

```
  "permissions": [
    "*://thesaurus.altervista.org/*"
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check that your script is declaring required permissions, as described here:
    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission
    https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external

Inside your manifest there should be something like:

```
"permissions": [
  "*http://thesaurus.altervista.org/*"
],
```